# Search nearby points from a geography column

Tags: sql, geolocation, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlgeography

I have a geography typed column in my table with spatial index. How can I select the top N rows that is within X meters of a given Latitude/Longitude while making use of the index to improve performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say 'while making use of the index' - how do you mean?

I've only just started (today) experimenting with SQL 2012 and its `Geography` datatype, but maybe the following is useful - I do realise you're using `2008-R2`

Create some data:

```
CREATE TABLE SpatialTable 
    ( id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    GeogCol1 geography, 
    GeogCol2 AS GeogCol1.STAsText() );
GO

INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeogCol1)
VALUES 
(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.360 47.656)',4326)),
(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.343 47.656)',4326)),
(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.358 47.660)',4326)),
(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.348 47.649)',4326)),
(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.348 47.658)',4326)),
(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.358 47.653)',4326))
```

Create index:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX Spatialindex ON SpatialTable ( GeogCol1 ) USING GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (
    GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_4 = MEDIUM),
    CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
)
```

Define point of interest:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);
```

Find closest 2, within 750m of point

```
SELECT TOP 2
        @g.STDistance(st.GeogCol1) AS [DistanceFromPoint (in meters)] 
    ,   st.GeogCol2
    ,   st.id
FROM    SpatialTable st WITH(INDEX(SpatialIndex))
WHERE   @g.STDistance(st.GeogCol1) <= 750
ORDER BY @g.STDistance(st.GeogCol1) ASC
```

Gives:

```
DistanceFromPoint (in meters) GeogCol2                 id
----------------------------- ------------------------ -----------
234.715604015178              POINT (-122.348 47.649)  4
711.760044795868              POINT (-122.358 47.653)  6
```

The `SQL Execution Plan` suggests the index is being used, and [this website](http://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-is-it-between.htm) suggests the distances returned are correct

Let me know if this isn't what you need, I'm trying to learn this myself so any revision is good!

*** Edit ****
I've added an index table hint to force the query to use the index (as per this [MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/isaac/archive/2008/08/29/is-my-spatial-index-being-used.aspx)). The link explains the index probably wasn't used initially as SQL determined it would be faster not to use the index. The Execution Plan of my example above shows a 97%/3% split of using/not using the index, so in this instance the SQL optimiser had the right idea.

*Why* queries are slower when using the index appears to be the subject of numerous blog posts and questions here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708323/spatial-index-slowing-down-query).

Comment: looks like this is what it need. i'll check if this makes use of the spatial index i added.

Comment: the execution plan doesn't show that it's using the spatial index

Comment: @Bahamut As per (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/isaac/archive/2008/08/29/is-my-spatial-index-being-used.aspx) I've added an index hint, which works

Comment: Hey Thanks Paddy, this worked, I verified this with actual latitude and longitude from google maps. Only question I have is, this returns me actual distance between two points, as per my understanding it is air distance...correct?

Comment: From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb933808.aspx) 

`STDistance() returns the shortest LineString between two geography types. This is a close approximate to the geodesic distance. The deviation of STDistance() on common earth models from the exact geodesic distance is no more than .25%. This avoids confusion over the subtle differences between length and distance in geodesic types.`