# Optimum spatial index configuration for towns locations?

Tags: sql-server, spatial-index

What would be optimal spatial index configuration (tessellation, cells per object, grid granularity per level) for a table that contains one of European towns locations - in form of 'POINT (long lat)'. There is roughly 10000 rows.

Simple querying scenarios include distance queries - like 'query me all towns in 10 km radius'

Comment: Two things: 1) The WKT for your point is backwards; it's POINT(Long, Lat). 2) My gut says to have at least the first two levels be low resolution since your points are in such a small part of the world.

Comment: @Ben Thul - you are right, corrected

Answer (score 0):

Great question. I answered this same question [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15842694/2250424). It involves running a stored procedure which will test each of the tessellation permutations and give you a table of results that will help you select the proper cells per object and HIGH/MEDIUM/LOW settings. Hope it helps.

In addition, if you have the option of using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use the GEOMETRY_AUTO_GRID tessellation which generally performs really well.